# Jquery dialog not working in dual monitor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-dialog

There is one Jquery dialog on one of my web pages. I work on a dual monitor system.
The problem is that, I am not able to move/drag the Jquery dialog from one monitor to another monitor screen.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: $('.xxxxx').dialog({
                        autoOpen: true,
                        position: 'top',
                        width: $(window).width() - 600,
                        height : $(window).height(),
                        modal: false,
                        closeOnEscape: false,
                        title: 'Document(s)',
                    })

Comment: On your body, set css properties for top, left, bottom & right to 0 and make sure you have jQuery core, jQuery UI (for dialog) and jQuery [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) (part of jQuery UI) implemented.

Comment: @urbz: thanks for this. Can I ask, set css properties for body or div that is used for dialog?

Comment: Since `body` contains all the contents of a HTML document, you need make it boundless in order to allow dragging the dialog from one screen to another. Your `<div>` for the dialog is part of that, so it's not that element that needs to be boundless. **Note**: I am also assuming that you are referring to the same browser across two screens - because the answers provided here are not stupid, since the element is bounded within the body that itself is an object of the browser.

Comment: yes Sir, the same browser is used. I am trying with what you have said. Your reply is very important for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I think UI Dialog works only on window based and if you drag it to another monitor then it will not move to another monitor.

UI Dialog will not move from browser window to other window.

Comment: So is it better to do things in a new windows rather than in a dialog? If you are sure, I can proceed on a new window. Please reply.

Comment: Yes, because dialog html code is written for one window, you can get it using ajax for opening in multiple windows.

Comment: using ajax means opening dialog by using ajax. Sorry I am not familiar with it. Can you give some reference so that I can work with that ?.

Comment: @RajuSNair "better" depends on your requirements. Personally I'd rather have dialogs in a browser rather than the MS CRM style dozens of dialogs

Answer (score 2):

any JQuery or other dialog works inside browser ... scratch your browser in two screen and it will work inside browser borders

Answer (score 1):

A jQuery Dialog can only live inside the webpage it's declared in, it is after all only a div.

I assume what's happening is you're trying to drag a div outside the browser window (onto your second screen). I'm afraid you can't do this.