# Jquery Dialog Not Working in Dual Monitor - Follow Up

Tags: jquery, asp.net, browser, jquery-ui-dialog

On one of my webpage there is a link. When clicked on this link, One Image Slider will come. I have did the Image Slider in a Jquery Dialog. And there are calls between the dialog and parent page.  But then came to know that, Jquery dialog will not work in dual monitor screen.

I am planning to implement the Image slider in a new browser window. But that require more effort and more calls between two pages than current.

Please suggest me the best way to implement this Image slider ? Is it better to do in a new browser window or there have any other way to do. Please help.

Comment: Could you please elaborate with examples/code snippets and/or previous attemps on what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: @urbz - thanks for coming. I hope, u were on the last discussion . The link is given below.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260361/jquery-dialog-not-working-in-dual-monitor/25260391#25260391
Now what I need is, instead of jquery dialog, I like to open in a new window. Is it better or any other way like new window ?

Comment: I just wants to do in the shortest and easiest way

Comment: Last night I am not able to move jquery dialog out of the browser window

Comment: Why invest so much time and effort enabling to try and move the jQuery dialog out of the browser when it's really complex and part of the browser as an object? You should be working with `<iframes>` then I presume. Providing an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [**jQuery dialog**](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) is an object part of the browser. Therefore - it is really complex and/or impossible to split it across two browsers on dual monitors.

I really recommend that you'd better be working with it as it is intended, or reconsider using an `<iframe>`. More info about it here: [**Link**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

I provided you with an example containing a simple [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) function that renders up a new `<iframe>` window with another [**jsfiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/urbz/4b1j2ab4/1/) link I made containing a jQuery dialog. This way you could work with having dialogs on embedded documents and call them from your existing window using iframes.

```
$("#clickme").click(function () {
    var url = "http://fiddle.jshell.net/urbz/4b1j2ab4/1/show/";
    $('<iframe />', {
        name: 'frame',
        id: 'frame',
        src: url
    }).css({
        width: '1000px',
        height: '1000px'
    }).appendTo('body');
});
```

## JsFiddle Example

Comment: Thanks for this valuable effort. But can I ask, Is it possible to move this Iframe from one monitor to another monitor in a dual screen environment.

Comment: In order to move to another monitor, I am opening the Image slider in a new browser window so that, it can be dragged to a new monitor.

Comment: If I understand you correctly - opening up a new window on a clients second monitor programmatically is not something I know is possible, nor how to do it. That is probably not doable, and the client needs to do this him/herself.

Comment: No, the new window can be opened on the monitor where the parent page is present. The issue is from there, I am dragging to the second monitor. In the case of dialog it is not possible. I have already started to open a new window and then appending the needed div to that window. So that that window can be dragged to the second monitor.